# Namespaces and autoloading in a PHP framework

Tags: php

I have two folders in my project: APPLICATION and SYSTEM. System contains folders such as CONFIG, CORE, HTML, URL. Each one of them contain some sets of classes.

I use this convention: the namespace of the class mirrors its file structure - this allows me to autoload them easily.

So: `\Project_Name\System\Core\Foo` is placed in `System/Core/Foo.php`.

However, calling such a long names is not the quickest, and nicest way for users of my code. Two questions then:

1. Is it O.K. to create a couple of empty classes with the namespace like \Project_Name? With one "use" keyword in application classes I would get rid of the problem. But as a consequence I'd get a lot of empty classes and folder structures in a strange folder in "system/".
2. Or maybe I should be simply using `\Project_Name` in every class? This however would make me push to create longer class names which would mirror the file structure, and make autoloading less understandable.

What do you think is the best way?

Comment: Well, what do you think works best?

Comment: I 'm not sure what the problem is. Your users can write `use \Project_Name\System\Core\Foo` once and thereafter refer to just `Foo`, or -- even better -- their IDE can do this automatically.

Comment: Own framework. The problem is, I don't want to use "use" keyword for every class, because there's too much of them. I think the best is to use a single, simple namespace. But it made me wonder that projects like symphony use the whole file-structured namespaces.

And I'm not sure if it wouldn't mess the understandability too much.

Comment: Hm, projects like Symphony do indeed use \extremely\deep\paths\until\you\get\to\something\useful, the merit of this is highly debatable (pros & cons..), and if your framework/code does not need this, why would you do this to yourself? Contrary to what people might think. 1 or 2 levels of namespaces suffices for most projects I've ever seen. Mostly deep paths are abused as a kind of inheritance / type grouping thing that's often not needed unless you write majorly abstract code in a huge codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot solution 3: Use aslias

```
use \Project_Name\System\Core\Foo;
use \Project_Name\System\Core\Bar as CoreBar;
$x = new Foo;
$y = new CoreBar;
```

The problem with your both solutions is, that you let your laziness decide about your applications structure.

Comment: Yes, but not MY laziness. I don't want the lazy users of my code to abandon it because they have to use 500px wide class names.

Comment: If someone will want to write an anchor to the base file, he would do this with <a href="<?php echo URL::base() ?>">a</a>, and not with <a href="<?php echo \Project_name\System\Helpers\Url\Url::base() ?>">a</a>

Comment: Or maybe...can I use alias to the whole namespace? Maybe this would shorten class names a bit. The cool thing would be also using "use" keywords in just one superior class that's been extended by all others.

Comment: @user1615069 You really qualify classnames in _pixel_?!? (Beside this: The classnames in my example are just around 200px ;)) But yes, you can let an alias point to a namespace too: `use Foo\Bar; new Bar\Baz()`. You definitely should read http://php.net/language.namespaces.importing and http://php.net/language.namespaces.rules The manual is your friend.

Comment: I can qualify them in percents if you want to :P Thanks.

Comment: @user1615069 Usually characters, because they are identifiers and nothing layout, or design related ;)